# Show different menu options on Toolbar for activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-toolbar

```
Android Studio 1.4
```

I have a Toolbar that I inflate in my `activity_main.xml`.
I have a menu called `main.xml` that gets inflated that has just 1 icon to display on it.

When the user clicks to open a fragment. I have another menu `friends.xml` that has 2 icons.

When I inflate the friends menu in the fragment it still displays the icon from the `main.xml` menu.

I thought that inflating a new menu on the toolbar would remove the existing menu.

This is a screenshot of the main.xml menu. The find icon is displayed
[image]

This is the screenshot of the fragment as you can see the find icon is still there.

[image]
`activity_main.xml` with toolbar included

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tbMain"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is my code for create the menu in MainActivity.java

```
    private void setupToolBar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tbMain);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And in my fragment I have this, as you can see I am inflating the friends.xml menu.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.friends, menu);
    }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: "I thought that inflating a new menu on the toolbar would remove the existing menu" this is not valid, total Menu Items = MenuItemsOfActivity+MenuItemsOfFragment

Comment: just move `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }`  inside FirstFragment and do setHasOptionsMenu(true) inside the FirstFragment's onCreate().. This should work

Comment: No need to inflate menu inside activity..just do it fragment wise

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this with `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. I think your better bet will be [`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29).

You can force Android to refresh the options menu by simply writing [`getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) in Fragment's `onResume()`.

So your `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` will look like:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.clear();    //remove all items
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);
}
```

Comment: This was the way I solved it as it seems to be very clean. Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to apply different colours for the toolbar icons on separate Fragments? E.g. Fragment_1 I'd like the icons to be white, while Fragment_2 to be black

Comment: @AndroidDevBro I tink you'll have to change the toolbar theme from your fragment, from lifecycle methods like `onResume()`

Comment: @Sufian Thanks for replying. Could you be a little bit more specific though; would this go in the `XFragment` method, the `onCreateView` method or simply in the root of the `Fragment's` class?

Comment: I believe doing it in `onResume()` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Store the `menu` reference in a variable.

```
 private Menu menu;

       @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            this.menu = menu;
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

When replacing to mentioned fragment do the following.

```
private void hideOption(int id) {
        menu.findItem(id).setVisible(false);
    }
```

Call `hideOption()` with menu id. for ex,

```
hideOption(R.id.action_search);
```

And vice versa for showing.or follow suggestion of #Droidwala